# Toast run before called method

Tags: java, android

I have the following code to get an integer data count.`getData(NewsSettings)` method returns 3. When I click on the button, the app shows me `No new news found`.

Why it runs the toast before getData?

**UPDATED**

I have added the complete `onCreate` and `getData` methods. When I run, it shows me `No new news found` then `Inside Response` then `Data count = 3`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.action_profile);

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBuilder);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newsSettings = new NewsSettings();
            newsSettings.setPreferredCity(pref.getString("prefCity", ""));
            int dataCount = getData(newsSettings);
            if(dataCount > 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dataCount + " new news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No new news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private int getData(NewsSettings newsSettings) {
    final int[] data = {0};

    RequestInterface requestInterface = RequestHelper.getInstance().getRequest();

    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation("dataCount");
    request.setNewsSettings(newsSettings);

    Call <ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback <ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call <ServerResponse> call,
                               retrofit2.Response <ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                data[0] = resp.getNewsSettings().getDataCount();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data count = " + data[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return data[0];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? dataCount must be < 0 to write the toast "No new news found"

Comment: I don't believe you.  Do you have any evidence that the Toast is sent before getData is run?

Comment: You should put the code for "getData", and check debugger. This seems wrong at many levels because i think you oversimplified your code, and doing so, removed the error or hiden it. Btw, just try with "int dataCount=3;" just to check but i'm pretty sure the problem is the getData method.

Comment: I have updated my code @Feuby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning right value i.e, less than or equal to 0. Why? Because, when you click on button it calls `getData()` method which contains an Asynchronous network call method of Retrofit. In which `data[0]` variable gets filled with the value after your get `onResponse()` method called.

So, at the same time the program cursor completes its first execution which started when you clicked on some button.

You can modify your code like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ....
  ....

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       newsSettings = new NewsSettings();
       newsSettings.setPreferredCity(pref.getString("prefCity", ""));

       /** here is the modification **/
       getData(newsSettings);
  }

}
```

And in your `getData()` method remove `int` return type and use `void`

```
private void getData(NewsSettings newsSettings) {  // remove int return type

   .....
   .....

   response.enqueue(new Callback <ServerResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call <ServerResponse> call,
                           retrofit2.Response <ServerResponse> response) {
          ServerResponse resp = response.body();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
              data[0] = resp.getNewsSettings().getDataCount();

           /** here is the modification ***/
              displayDataCount(data[0]);  // call to displayCount() method

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data count = " + data[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call <ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
          Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  });

}
```

And create another method called `displayDataCount()` like this where you can display the data count

```
private void displayDataCount(int dataCount) {
   if(dataCount > 0)
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dataCount + " new news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   else
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No new news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure if returned value `dataCount` is `greater than 0`. Debug it or remove if-else and just display `dataCount` using single makeToast method.

Comment: Then who call the makeText to it can run?

Comment: It was like you said before. No if-else but I added it for more clarification